# How to get the selected value of a dynamic drop down in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am creating dynamic drop down in my template. I can't get the selected value of those.

```
var newjobDropDown = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'jobDropDown' + counter);

newjobDropDown.after().html('<label><?php echo __(Job Vacancy); ?></label>' +
                            '<select  id="jobDropDown' + counter +'"'+' onchange="validate()"'+' class="vacancyDrop"'+'>'+buildVacancyList()+'</select>'+
                            '<span onclick="removeDrop(event)"'+'class="removeText"'+ 'id="removeButton'+counter+'">'+remove+'</span>'+'<br class="clear" />');

newjobDropDown.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
```

I used the following code to get the value, but i got a null value.

```
$('#jobDropDown1').val()
```

Comment: you use same `id` for both `div` and `select`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
$('#jobDropDown1').val()
```

but you select looks like

```
<select id="jobDropDown'
```

Add `1` to its id and it will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have posted it looks like you are creating two elements with the same `id`—the `select` and a preceding `div`. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> If more than one element has been
>   assigned the same ID, queries that use
>   that ID will only select the first
>   matched element in the DOM.

This means your code is trying to get the `value` of the `div` element, rather than that of the `select`. Try giving the `div` a different `id`:

```
var newjobDropDown = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'jobDropDown_div' + counter);

newjobDropDown.after().html('<label><?php echo __(Job Vacancy); ?></label>' +
                            '<select  id="jobDropDown' + counter +'"'+' onchange="validate()"'+' class="vacancyDrop"'+'>'+buildVacancyList()+'</select>'+
                            '<span onclick="removeDrop(event)"'+'class="removeText"'+ 'id="removeButton'+counter+'">'+remove+'</span>'+'<br class="clear" />');

newjobDropDown.appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');
```

Comment: you use same `id` for both `div` and `select`. Why?

Comment: Please read my answer again. The code I posted will create a `div` with an ID of `jobDropDown_div(N)` followed by a `select` with an ID of `jobDropDown(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have repetated `id`s (you shouldn't have).
You have 2 choices:

1) Change to different id, then select it with jquery normally

2) If you can't don't want, you should do:

```
$('select#jobDropDown1').val()
```

With this, we're differentiating both equal ids by tag name.

Hope this helps. Cheers